# Alertbox, CountDownTimer, Back button crash

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have an app that runs a countdown timer and brings up an alertbox when the timer runs out so that the game can restart. Unfortunately, when I hit the back button and open up the app again, it crashes around the time when the original countdowntimer should have run out.

The following code is located in onCreate of my Activity.

```
        CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(totalTime*1000, 1000) { 
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            time = (int) ((millisUntilFinished)/1000)*100/totalTime;             
            TimeBar.setProgress(time);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            time = 0;            
            TimeBar.setProgress(time);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            alertbox.setMessage("Sweet! " + score + " points!");
            alertbox.setPositiveButton("Leaderboard", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    ScoreloopManagerSingleton.get().onGamePlayEnded((double) score, null);
                    startActivity(new Intent(BubblesActivity.this, LeaderboardsScreenActivity.class));
                    BubblesActivity.this.finish();

                }
            });
            alertbox.setNeutralButton("Replay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    BubblesActivity.this.finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(BubblesActivity.this, BubblesActivity.class));

                }
            });
            if(alertbox!= null)
                alertbox.show();



        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a stack trace it's hard to say what happens but it most likely has something to do you referencing a dead `Activity` from your `CountDownTimer`.

Calling `enter code here`CountDownTimer.cancel() in `onDestroy()` would probably solve this.

Comment: I believe you are correct. I attempted to do this, but am having the problem that because of where CountDownTimer is declared it is not in scope for the onDestory() or onPause().

Additionally, and this is embarrassing, I haven't for the life of me been able to figure out how to locate and copy my stack trace's despite viewing a bunch of other posts explaining it.

Comment: You should put "CountDownTimer cdt" in your Activity. You can find stacktraces in logcat, either via a tab in eclipse or typing logcat in your terminal.